# Trouble accessing multiple array data in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am putting the data in multiple array in php and trying to access it through key value pair logic but not getting success

Here's the output when I'm printing the array with `print_r`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [33] => Coca Cola Products 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [1] => Agricultural products, Food and Beverages 
    ) 
)
```

The code I'musing:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$option)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

output required:

```
33 coca cola products
1 Agricultural products, Food and Beverages
```

In my `for`-loop for populating data I'm doing this:

```
$data[] = array($loop['category_id'] => $loop['category_name']);
```

Now wanted to get category id and category name

Comment: what are you trying to geT?

Comment: @Exprator updated the question kindly check

Comment: I'm guessing that category_id's are unique? Why not build you're array like this instead: `$data[$loop['category_id']) = $loop['category_name'];` and just do this in your foreach: `echo $key . ' ' . $option;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you populating the array...

```
data[] = array($loop['category_id'] => $loop['category_name']);
```

Your creating each element as an array, which is why you end up with the end result you have.

If you used

```
$data[$loop['category_id']] = $loop['category_name'];
```

You would see that the array is created at 1 level of depth.  Use print_r on this and you will see the difference. This will mean when you iterate over with the `foreach` it will use the keys you used to add the data and give the values your after.

Comment: If you're gonna copy/paste my comment, make sure you fix the error in it. :-) It should be `$data[$loop['category_id']]` and not `$data[$loop['category_id'])` (the last parenthesis).

Comment: The problem I have with comments is that they don't always explain what the problem is, and sorry about copy - it's caffeine hasn't kicked in yet and typing is hard work :-/

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that you did anything wrong. Just thought it was a bit funny. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your $data is an array of array, you should do it like this, **[live demo](https://eval.in/817447)**.

```
foreach ($data as $v)
{
    echo key($v) . ' ' . current($v) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as below

```
$data = array(array('33'=>"Coca Cola Products"),array("1"=>"Agricultural products, Food and Beverages"));

foreach ($data as $key=>$option)
{
        foreach($option as $k=>$v){
                echo "\n". $k ." ". $v;
        }
}
```